# How do you get hair to take on the color of the mesh it's attached to?

Tags: mesh, texturing, particles, hair

I'm still pretty new to Blender (currently using v2.9), so I'm probably just overlooking something basic, but I've been trying to add fur to this fox model's tail and no matter what I do, the fur remains black. [image: Fur remains black, despite being linked to the correct material.]

I've looked up tutorials, and in all of them, the hair/fur seems to automatically take on the color of the mesh. Am I doing something wrong? The texture has been assigned to the mesh, so that's not the problem. Also, I can't seem to pull up the hair in the node editor, or even select it. Could this be part of the problem? I've tried making the hair into an object, but this changes nothing. I can provide the blend file if that would help. Right now I'm just really confused.

Comment: In the Particle panel > Render > Material, make sure you have selected the same material as your object, and it should work

Comment: I've already selected the correct material, and it's still completely black. Also, when I choose to render it as an object, it completely disappears. Thanks for the suggestion, though. Also, for reference, I'm running a Windows 10 desktop with 16GB of RAM, an Intel i7-8700 CPU and a NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070 GPU.

Comment: maybe share your object (just a part of it, don't forget to pack the image texture): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a *Noise Texture* node plugged into the *Displacement* socket of the *Material Output*, it messes up the render.

I don't know what you were trying to do with it but anyway you can't directly plug a *Noise Texture* into the *Output*, you need at least to put a *Vector > Displacement* node between the 2.

[image]

Comment: Aha! That worked - I figured it was going to be some kind of beginner mistake like that. I was trying to give the skin a slight texture so it wouldn't be completely smooth in the places where it didn't have as much fur. I'll have to make it a priority to learn more about how nodes work. Anyways, thank you so much for the help!